# Interface Builder show all @IBInspectable in cascade

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ibdesignable, ibinspectable

I'm maybe too complicated, but here is what I want:

```swift
@IBDesignable
class A: UIView {
    @IBInspectable var title: String = "" {
        didSet {
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
}

@IBDesignable
class B: UIView {
    var firstView: A = A()
    var secondView: A = A()
}
```

The B class have 2 @IBDesignable classes, so if I want to customize B directly in Interface Builder, I can't as I don't have access to the 2 A classes.

At first I create a protocol to list all elements in A class, but when a view need 2 or more item of A class, I can't use this.

Do someone have an idea to have only 1 B class in my storyboard and can customize both A classes?

Comment: Not very sure, but do you think making these variables as public might help. I'll try to check this via coding it.

Comment: I try a lot of things in case some magic happens but no. Just check again and 'Show the attributes inspector' tab is still empty of custom @IBInspectable.

Comment: Give B the inspectable properties, e.g. firstViewTitle and secondViewTitle.

Comment: @matt My main problem is that if tomorrow I add an IBInspectable titleColor to the A class, I have nothing to prevent me to didn't forget to add 2 IBInspectable var to B class.

Comment: Too bad. If you cannot see the A in the storyboard, there is nothing to be inspect. You can only inspect what you can see.

Comment: I get down vote without explication, that's so sad. Do am I the only one to dream of a customizable Interface Builder where you can name your attributes group and show/hide like standard one? And with a recursive looking at IBInspectable variables?

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure if your this is possible. This is not usually possible even when you use Apple Library classes, for example a UIButton has a UIView and also a UILabel.

Though these different classes and some things are possible by overriding as explained [here](http://jamesonquave.com/blog/adding-ibinspectable-to-a-superclass-in-swift/)

But I can provide you a hack here. In the object that you create for Object B in storyboard, you can add `User Defined Runtime Attributes` as follows -

`firstView.title`  & `secondView.title`

I know this might not be the answer you are looking for, but thats just a way around.